# How to "run 'dmesg' using only the 'find' command"?

Tags: find, dmesg

For one of my lab assignments, I need to "run `dmesg` using only the `find` command".

I have been trying to look and can't find anything probably because its not the way it's supposed to be used.

Comment: `dmesg` accesses the kernel log ring through `/dev/kmsg`. I don't see what the `find` command has to do with it.

Comment: Neither do I that's why the question is confusing me it just says to run the application dmesg using only the find command.

Comment: "for one of my labs" -- there's the magic reason, the one that allows tossing all sense out of a window... As a hint, so you can have some fun figuring it out: `find` can run commands, no, let's say it can `exec`ute them. There's nothing to say you couldn't run `dmesg` via it too. Just that it's silly, and you still need a shell to start `find`, so it's not like you'd be using "only" `find`. The shell + `find` + `dmesg` is more more complex than just the shell + `dmesg`. If it were me, I'd say that to whoever is running the labs, but you might want to be careful with that...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

```
find $(which find) -exec dmesg \;
```

This should be one solution. `$(which find)` can be replaced with the path to any file that you are sure exists. `find` will execute the command provided to `-exec` for each file that is found (which in our case, is just once).

Comment: Well... `find /dev/kmsg -exec dmesg \;` would be better, and more to the point. Utterly pointless though.

Answer (score 2):

Executing single commands is something that `find` can do, but that you would never use it for doing.  It's a bit like coming up with one of those useless machines you can find [videos of on YouTube](https://youtu.be/MiG13q79iQE).

Using standard `find`, you could execute `dmesg` using the following command.

```bsh
find . -prune -exec dmesg \;
```

In this `find` command, we try to execute `dmesg` using `-exec` for the current directory, and we use `-prune` to avoid searching the current directory for anything.  With nothing else to explore, `find` terminates.

The command does not depend on what search path we give to `find` other than it should exist. It also does not depend on the current user being allowed to execute `dmesg` or having `dmesg` in their `$PATH`.  The command will run the `dmesg` utility pretty much as if executed from the command line directly.

Comment: Note that both of those depend on `dmesg` exiting successfully. ;) If you make the mistake of running `find -exec dmesg \; -quit` without privilege on a Linux host, you'll get a screenful of "dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted" errors, one for each file. You could do `find . -prune -exec dmesg \;` to avoid that, since `-prune` succeeds and doesn't terminate. (Harder with `-quit` since it does terminate immediately, you'd need something like `find . -exec dmesg \; -quit -or quit`)

Comment: @ilkkachu I would have thought that running `dmesg` successfully was a prerequisite of the task.  If that's not possible, the task is even more useless.

Comment: yes, of course there's no sense in running `dmesg` when knowing it's going to fail. But in general, it's probably worth remembering that `-exec` is also a condition. (of course `-exec {} +` isn't, so if one just wants to run a command for each in a set of files, with `-prune` after or not, they can use the `+` variant and there's no problem.)

Comment: @ilkkachu Updated after reconsidering what you've contributed.

Comment: I suspect the premise is that the OP would only have access to a restricted shell where only a small set of commands are available, and one such command is `find` and whoever deployed that restricted shell overlooked the fact that `find` can run any command regardless of whether the shell `find` is invoked from is restricted or not.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, ok. And executing a shell would obviously give you an unrestricted shell. I see.

Answer (score 0):

Given what has been written in the comments, I think the correct answer is `find / -name dmesg -type f -executable -exec {} \;`